# Proper Syntax for AND OR NOT Excel Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, office365

I was practicing some basic formulas in excel. The last 3 I worked on are as follows:

```
    =IF((OR(C4="Hourly",C4="Contract")),"Yes","No")
    
    =IF((AND(B4="Marketing",G4< 50000)),"increase", "")
    
    =NOT(OR(B4="Manufacturing",B4="Product "))
```

These 3 statements are correct and are working, But I don't understand why the "NOT OR Statement" does not have two parenthesis" "=NOT(OR(..." like the others. "IF((or(..." "IF((AND(..."

If somebody could explain this to me in would deepen my understanding.

Thank you so much,
Cole

Comment: Note that in Excel, AND/OR/NOT are functions just like SUM or AVERAGE. Functions take their arguments in brackets directly after the function name, so there is no ambiguity where the result of the function should be used. In contrast, operators like + or / take their arguments on both sides of the operator, which might necessitate the use of brackets e.g. `=6 / 2 / 3` vs `=6 / (2 / 3)`. What may be additionally confusing is that some programming languages implement AND/OR/NOT as operators instead of functions.

Comment: AND is that all conditions must be met, and OR only needs to meet one of the conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double-parenthesis are superfluous.

This also works very well :

```
=IF(OR(C4="Hourly",C4="Contract"),"Yes","No")
```

Enclosing the function within parenthesis serves no purpose at all.